# Why is the font-height equal to 20px when my font-size is 62.5% and height is 1.6rem?

Tags: html, css

I am using the Chrome browser and I have set up my html as follows:

```
html {
font-size: 62.5%;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

It's my understanding that this would normally mean that a 1rem is equal to 10px. I have more CSS below:

```
table.code pre > code {
margin: 0;
font-family: "xxxConsolas", "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Courier New", Courier, monospace !important;
font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="code">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>01</td>
         <td><pre><code>xxx</code></pre></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

However the text appears big and when I check it's equal to 20px.

Can someone explain what's happening?

Comment: Probably a Chrome bug. I dropped your code in a fiddle and the same problem occurs in Chrome while it works fine in IE and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/YHGL8

Comment: Do you have any ideas of a simple way to solve this. I've been happy changing things to rem until this came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My previous answer works but I'm not convinced it does so for the right reasons.**

Sizing both `pre` and `code` works and doesn't seem such of a hack:

replace

```
table.code pre > code {...
```

with:

```
table.code pre, table.code code {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "xxxConsolas", "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Courier New", Courier, monospace !important;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

[UPDATED DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YHGL8/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to normalise the base font size for more than just the `html` element. `<code>` is inheriting some size from `<pre>`.

```
html, pre {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

[DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YHGL8/2/)

Comment: Very strange, but whatever Chrome is doing to arrive at these calculations, it's doing it horribly wrong.

Comment: @BoltClock yeah, its the `<pre>` and `code` in combination its not liking. Either on their own seems fine. http://jsfiddle.net/YHGL8/6/